# My firebase storage function doesnt let me take the url from the function

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, url, firebase-storage

I'm new at programming and I'm so confused at this error because I want to have the download link into an array but it returns me empty but when I execute it with the console.log inside the .then it returns me the link but if I do it outside the the returns me nothing :(

```
 var title = "";
 var price = "";
 var description = "";
 var image = new Array();


firebase
.database()
.ref("/productos/" + itemId)
.on("value", (snapshot) => {
  title = snapshot.val().title;
  price = snapshot.val().price;
  description = snapshot.val().description;
});


firebase
    .storage()
    .ref("/images/" + itemId)
    .getDownloadURL()
    .then((url) => {
      image = [url];
      console.log(image)      
      setLoading(false);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
    console.log(image)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do some research on how promises work I think so you can understand whats going on. Your code looks ok but its a bit messy to be honest, maybe the below using async/await instead of promise chaining can help  you. I just created this function to model how the logic works, not because its going to be useful.

```
// Global array variable image
const image = new Array();
const itemId = 'an_id';

const addItemDownloadUrlToArray = async (ref) => {
  // Use async await not promise chaining
  const url = await firebase.storage().ref(ref).getDownloadURL();
  image.push(url);
};

// After this has run, image will have the url in it
addItemDownloadUrlToArray(`/images/${itemId}`);
```

Comment: Thanks u bro Ill try it